# UIButton: Problems with automatic height adjustment

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIButton whose title is constantly changing and sometimes, the string I set it to exceeds the bounds of the frame.  Here's a hard-coded example of the issue I'm seeing.

[image: The issue in question]

I want the width to stay constant, the words to wrap, and the height to adjust accordingly.  So far, no luck on the third one.  Here's the code I currently have for setting the button's title:

```
[self.button    setTitle:@"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button sizeToFit];
[self.button setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: And yes, I am using AutoLayout for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing was creating an IBOutlet to the button's height constraint (did NOT know I could do that) and setting the constant to self.button.titleLabel.height.